# How can I strengthen my baby's arms?

Tags: infant, crawling

Our 11-month-old hasn't been too interested in learning to crawl. I think she got tired of failing. She pushes her self backwards but can't push herself forwards. While searching for activities that could strengthen her arms, the most promising I found was [baby pullups](http://www.livestrong.com/article/480817-baby-arm-strength-exercises/):

> When your baby can sit up, even with support, help him practice getting into a standing position. Hold onto baby's hands and gently pull baby from a seated into a standing position. You can count or say "up we go!" or something that will bring a smile to his face. He'll think it's a fun game, but he's also beefing up those baby muscles.

All other exercises seems to be geared to infants that are still trying to hold their toys, bu our daughter is beyond that. Moving her chubby self around required much more strength than waving a toy.

Are there any other activities we can do to help strengthen our daughter's arms?

Answer (score 5):

When she is on her tummy, put her favorite toy juuuust a bit out of reach so that she has to go to it. The effort of holding up her top half while also moving forward will give her a strong incentive, and (as long as you don't do it too much) can be fun.

Comment: Yeah, I think we went wrong by doing this too much. She's not very fond of it now.

Comment: We did this to great effect: http://www.markmroden.com/Kids/TMR/Thomas-McKenzie-Roden/7325221_pD4mT7#!i=609181998&k=j8gCP&lb=1&s=A

Answer (score 1):

11 months is not *that* late. Sure, some kids walk or talk at that age, but they are exceptions - every kid is unique, and in the end it doesn't really matter.

So, first of all: Don't stress yourself, she will learn it soon enough. Don't think she's lazy or has given up trying, though. It takes time and practice, and she'll get the hang of it eventually.

Second, you're mentioning *crawling* and *standing up* but these are different things of course. She's got to learn crawling before walking (although there are exceptions) so focus on that. [Will's answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5067/109) is fine and can work in lots of situations. *"Juuust out of reach"* is wonderful training.

If she can't she sit herself up, and/or can't remain sitting on her own, then she's just not ready for that yet. Sitting requires strong back muscles which is trained by being on the tummy and lifting the head.

Answer (score 0):

I know various infants who didn't really get crawling forwards for a long time, despite crawling backwards successfully for a while.  Two of mine got crawling easily but the other one didn't.

And apparently I didn't crawl- was a bit of a chubby baby so just sat about.

These things come at different times, I wouldn't worry at 11 months though.